# How to change isAdmin() to $session->isAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, function, session, variables

So I've looked through some php scripts, and I've seen `$session->isAdmin()` and I like the way it looks within code...

I realize that this is calling a function; however, I cannot get it to work.  I can get a function to call, but for some reason can't figure out how to label it as `$session->isAdmin()` over just calling  `isAdmin()`

Ex:

Creating the Function

```
function isAdmin() {
    return 1;
}
```

Echoing out the Function

```
if (isAdmin() == 1) {
    echo "admin";
}
```

How do I change `isAdmin()` to `$session->isAdmin()`?

I'm basically trying to learn something new while doing this as well so any documentation on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some `Session` class?

Comment: "and I like the way it looks" --- FDD - Fashion Driven Development

Comment: nope...how do I do that?  I know some php but not that much...learning as I go

Comment: Zerkms -> as in, it looks clean, and its using functions which I don't currently use....it would make things alot easier to read and modify, as well as code..so...yeah, I like the way it looks

Comment: @kdjernigan: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: @kdjernigan: "it would make things alot easier to read and modify" -- why do you think so? How can you measure something you don't know anything about? Adding object model into your code isn't free. It solves complexity issues in one place, and adds it in others.

Comment: "and its using functions" - it's actually using methods within a class.

Comment: Guys... how about stopping to bash the novice and being solution-oriented here? For ***s sake, if s.o. wants to move from functional programming towards OOP (especially in hardly typed PHP), that's a great thing and i won't care about their motivations - albeit the person only likes the looks of it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have observed is probably other frameworks' wrapper objects for user session handling.

Changing your code to an object will be good practice and could work like this:

```
<?php

/** Session.php  */
class Session 
{
    protected $isAdmin = 0;
    public function __construct() 
    {
        // ... do your session initialisation here ...
        if (USER_HAS_SOMESPECIAL_RIGHTS)
            $this->isAdmin = 1;
    }

    /**
    * Do we have admin rights?
    * @return bool
    */
    public function isAdmin() {
        return $this->isAdmin;
    }

    /**
    * Echoing out the current role in the system
    * @return string
    */
    public function getRole() {
        if ($this->isAdmin)
            return "admin";

        return "normal mortal being (at least not an admin)."
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
include 'Session.php';
$session = new Session();   // This is when your code in __construct will be evaluated
echo $session->getRole();
```

Of course this is just a simple example, once you get into OOP you'll see you can abstract this to far greater extent. Hope this helps!

Comment: I pasted all this on one page and it worked fine; however, what if I wanted to have the session class in a separate page and use it via an include..is this possible?

Comment: Updated my post to reflect your requirement. Again: really simple, in a full fledged project you'll probably want to put your classes in namespaces and use lazy-autoloading (includes are superfluous in such a scenario).

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Session' not found in /xx/xx/public_html/test.php on line 3  It's not pulling the session from the include for some reason

Comment: Please try using an absolute path in your include, that has to work, otherwise your file `session.php` doesn't exist or is in a forbidden location. When it works, make sure you're using the correct relative path. NB: **When you include file B from file A, then any relative paths in B are using the location of A**

Comment: I do know how to use includes, and the file is being pulled in because other variables are working in that file.  It just won't pull the session class in...

Comment: I'd try `require` Session.php, does it still work past that line? If yes, then there must be a typo in the class name Session. I assume you're not using namespaces, that could be another thing interfering that i could think of. Or maybe you are trying to include your class within another class? Hard to diagnose from here... As your initial question got solved, you probably might want to open a separate question for that unless it is sorted now.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I will continue messing with it and attempt to get a working solution.  Lots to learn with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do with "$session"...

I can imagine that you have a session variable, let's call it `$_SESSION['user_type']` that holds 1 if admin and 0 if user.

Now you want a function that spells out admin or user?

```
function isAdmin($type) {
    if ($type==1) echo "Admin";
    elseif ($type==0) echo "User";
    else echo "And who are you!?";
}
```

Calling it:

```
isAdmin($_SESSION['user_type']);
```

Comment: Reckoning because the question was "How do I change isAdmin() to $session->isAdmin()?" :D